# Stop showing "Suggesting Edits Pending Approval" when I'm past my quota

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits

As a newly minted 10K rep user my status bar now has a few new icons. One of them indicates how many "Suggesting Edits Pending Approval" there are in the queue with a dark orange background. When I complete my possible 20 edits for the allotted time-span however, the icon still stays lit up:

[image]

**Suggestion:** Remove the icon while my cooldown is in effect. Once it's up, I'll know I can go back to approving edits. If you want to keep the queue number still up, at least have it change color to indcate that "there is work to be done" **and** "you have the ability to do this work".